# How to identify if a point (created by latitude and longitude) is inside or cross a polygon in Python?

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas

Context: I've two Excel files, in one of them (Table A) there is a table as is described below:

| vehicle | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 19.5167 | -99.2167 |
| B | 31.5197 | -100.2456 |

The second one (Table B), have a table that has the columns as follow:

| id of place | polygon |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | ((-99.2167 19.5167, -99.2169 19.5168, -99.2167 19.5167)) |
| 2824 | ((-203.327 49.5167, -203.3320 49.5183, -203.327 49.5167)) |

**I need to identify if the points of Table A, given by the latitude of longitude are crossing or are inside of the polygon of the table B.**

I've been made research and everything points to use Geopandas but is in the documentation saids is needed to use a shapefile to create a relation, is there other option to create something as my expected result?

Expected result (Table A with a flag column that allows to identify if the point is or not in the polygon)

| vehicle | latitude |
| --- | --- |
| A | True |
| B | False |

If you could tell me some clues of where I can find something would be awesome.

Comment: What you have aren't polygons... those are lines~

Comment: those are just a dummy examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd
```

dfA

```
  vehicle  latitude  longitude
0       A   19.5167   -99.2167
1       B   31.5197  -100.2456
```

dfB

```
   id of place                                            polygon
0         1234  ((-99.2167 19.5167, -99.2169 19.5168, -99.2167...
1         2824  ((-203.327 49.5167, -203.3320 49.5183, -203.32...
```

---

Doing:

```
# Make them proper Geometrys.
dfA['point'] = gp.GeoSeries.from_xy(dfA.longitude, dfA.latitude)
dfB['polygon'] = gp.GeoSeries.from_wkt('POLYGON' + dfB.polygon)

# Make them GeoDataFrames.
dfA = gp.GeoDataFrame(dfA, geometry='point')
dfB = gp.GeoDataFrame(dfB, geometry='polygon')
```

Here's what they look like now:

```
>>> dfA
  vehicle  latitude  longitude                        point
0       A   19.5167   -99.2167   POINT (-99.21670 19.51670)
1       B   31.5197  -100.2456  POINT (-100.24560 31.51970)
>>> dfB
   id of place                                            polygon
0         1234  POLYGON ((-99.217 19.517, -99.217 19.517, -99....
1         2824  POLYGON ((-203.327 49.517, -203.332 49.518, -2...
```

Get your answer:

```
# Use whatever function fits best, here I've used intersects:
out = dfA.intersects(dfB)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

See [`geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects.html#geopandas-geoseries-intersects) and look around the documentation... it's very helpful.

Comment: It does know that they're invalid geometries, but it tries to play nicely anyways. See `dfB.is_valid`